# Triggering StatefulWidget changes from appbar.actions

Tags: flutter, widget, state

I have a problem understanding how to update a widget from dynamic AppBar action buttons. Here is the flutter 'new app' I changed to illustrate the problem.
In my production app I need to show certain action buttons depending on the page widget currently shown in the drawer scaffold body.

```
class ActionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final action = IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      //state.action();
    },
  );

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ActionWidgetState();
  }
}

class ActionWidgetState extends State<ActionWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void action() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final actionWidget = ActionWidget();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          actionWidget.action,
        ],
      ),
      body: actionWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

How do I update widget state when action onPressed is triggered? My current workaround is this (obviously not optimal)

```
class MeasurePage extends PageWidget {
  MeasurePageState state;

  @override
  State createState() => state = MeasurePageState();
...
    onPressed: () {
      state.search(context);
    },
```

EDIT. Another sample with a drawer menu that better demonstrates the problem

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final actionWidgets = List<ActionWidget>.from([ActionWidget(1), ActionWidget(2)]);
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: actionWidgets[selectedIndex],
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[actionWidgets[selectedIndex].getAction()],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 33,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('instance 1'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
                this.setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = 0;
                });
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('instance 2'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close the drawer
                this.setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = 1;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ActionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final actionWidgetState;
  final index;
  ActionWidget(this.index)
      : this.actionWidgetState = ActionWidgetState(index),
        super(key: GlobalKey());

  Widget getAction() {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () {
        actionWidgetState.actionCallback();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => actionWidgetState;
}

class ActionWidgetState extends State<ActionWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;
  VoidCallback actionCallback;
  final index;

  ActionWidgetState(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    actionCallback = () => action();
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Page ${widget.index}',
          ),
          Text(
            'State $index',
          ),
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void action() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the StatefulWidget correctly. The action button you're calling in StatefulWidget should just be the button itself and then you can pass the data you want to change in your state to the statefulWidget class. Then in your State class you could override didUpdateWidget and setState within that. Perhaps go through this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

Answer (score 0):

Output:

[image]

Change your `ActionWidget` to this.

```
class ActionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  static final ActionWidgetState actionWidgetState = ActionWidgetState();
  final action = IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () {
      actionWidgetState.action();
    },
  );

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return actionWidgetState;
  }
}
```

---

Full code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));

class ActionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  static final ActionWidgetState actionWidgetState = ActionWidgetState();
  final action = IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    onPressed: () => actionWidgetState.action(),
  );

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => actionWidgetState;
}

class ActionWidgetState extends State<ActionWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
          Text('$_counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void action() => setState(() => _counter++);
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final actionWidget = ActionWidget();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(actions: <Widget>[actionWidget.action]),
      body: actionWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already. Regret it fails an assert in framework.dart, line 3819 when a state is recreated.

Comment: OK, I have updated the full code with output, please take a look now.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but 'static final' won't cut it. Add a drawer menu with two instances of ActionWidget and both will share the same state. 'final' sans static will crash on drawer switch.